# Radiobutton ou botão para ordenar dados

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, expressões-lambda

Em meu projeto, tenho uma tabela de Ocorrências e uma coluna chamada Status e os valores do Status são: pendente ou resolvido.

Preciso ordenar os dados e criar uma lógica que em minha *view* eu tenha um botão, ou dois, e ao clicar mostre todas as ocorrências que estão com o Status pendente ou resolvido. Ou seja, dois botões um para mostrar todas que estão pendentes e um para para mostrar todas as que estão resolvidas.

Como que eu faria isso ? Será que alguém poderia me ajudar ? Não uma noção de como fazer isso.

*Obs: Se puder ser por *radiobuttons*, seria mais prático.

Comment: Adicione na pergunta o que você já tem de código. :-)

Comment: Então esse é o problema, não sei como criar uma action e usá-la em um radio button para fazer essa criteria. :(. Posso fazer essa verificação via html também ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complementando a resposta do Cigano, para que funcionasse no meu cenário tive que fazer algumas alterações.

Primeiramente, eu criei a *Action*:

```
 public ActionResult Ordenar(String status, int? pagina)
    {
        var lista = db.Ocorrencias.Where(o => o.Status == status).Include(o => o.Aluno).ToList();

        int paginaTamanho = 10;
        int paginaNumero = (pagina ?? 1);
        return View(lista.ToPagedList(paginaNumero, paginaTamanho));
    }
```

Depois, eu criei um *PartialView* dessa *Action*:

```
<h3>Busca por Status</h3>

<div class="alert-info">
<form action="/Ocorrencias/Ordenar" id="status">
    Ordenar por:
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="Pendente" onclick="myFunction()">Pendente
    <input type="radio" name="status" value="Resolvido" onclick="myFunction()">Resolvido
</form>
</div>

 <table class="table table-striped">
 <tr>
     <th>
         Nome do Aluno
     </th>
    <th>
        Status
    </th>
    <th>
        Data de Entrada
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Aluno.NomeAluno)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Status" id="Status" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)" readonly class="Status" />
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataOcorrencia)
        </td>
        <td>
           <a href="~/Ocorrencias/Edita?id=@item.OcorrenciaID" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
           <a href="~/Ocorrencias/Detalhes?id=@item.OcorrenciaID" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span></a>
           <a href="~/Ocorrencias/Remove?id=@item.OcorrenciaID" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>                
        </td>
    </tr>
    }

   </table>

   Página @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) de          @Model.PageCount
   @Html.PagedListPager(Model, pagina => Url.Action("Ordenar", new { pagina, filtro = ViewBag.Filtro }))

 //Esse *script* faz com que o *radio* tenha o mesmo comportamento de um *button*
 <script>
 function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("status").submit();
 }
 </script>
```

E para que funcione perfeitamente o filtro, eu coloquei um *form* na minha *view* Index, que chama a *Action* Ordenar no *Controller* Ocorrencias.

```
//Demais controles da minha *view*
//Note no atributo *action* do *form* que chamo a *action* que será usada
<form action="/Ocorrencias/Ordenar" id="status">
Ordenar por:
<input type="radio" name="status" value="Pendente" onclick="myFunction()">Pendente
<input type="radio" name="status" value="Resolvido" onclick="myFunction()">Resolvido
</form>
//O restante dos controles
//Esse *script* faz com que o *radio* tenha o mesmo comportamento de um *button*
 <script>
 function myFunction() {
     document.getElementById("status").submit();
 }
 </script>
```

E dessa forma funcionou pra mim.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma lógica usando jQuery, por exemplo, que chame uma `Action` usando GET. Mais ou menos assim:

```
public ActionResult Listar(String status) 
{
    var lista = contexto.Ocorrencias.Where(o => o.Status == status).ToList();
    return View(lista);
}
```

`Status` pode ser um `RadioGroup`:

```
<input type="radio" name="status" value="P">Pendente<br>
<input type="radio" name="status" value="R">Resolvido
```

O gatilho pode ser algo assim:

```
$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: Não entendi muito bem esse gatilho... Ele funcionaria como um botão funciona ? Digo, ao clicar ele já mostraria ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Por aí. O que eu fiz ali é dar esse comportamento de botão pro *radio button*.

Comment: Aah. Entendi. E deixa eu te pergutar. Pra fazer essa ordenação, essa linha *String status*, recebe o valor de *pendente* ou *resolvido* aqui: *name="status"* ou aqui: *value="R"*

Comment: `name` diz ao `ModelBinder` qual o nome do campo, e `value` o valor. Note que no *Controller* eu especifiquei que o nome da variável a ser enviada é `status`. O resto o `ModelBinder` faz sozinho.

Comment: Então do jeito que ta ai, não preciso mexer, somente implementar que irá funcionar certo ?

Comment: Sim, com alguns ajustes, talvez. Não testei esse código.

Comment: Vou testar aqui pra ver se funciona. Eu poderia chamar essa action em outra, por exemplo, a Index ? Ou seja, na view Index ?

Comment: Aí é com você. Só sugeri uns nomes baseados no meu gosto.